# Validation of different types on different buttons click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a form which has 4 buttons on which are of type submit each submit hits a different `Action` in the `Controller`. For each button click I need to validate different inputs so I have a `click` event for the button with the same `class` as follows:

```
$('.store-action').click(function (e) {
    var ignoreValidationElements = [],
        id = $(this).attr("id"),
        name = $(this).attr("name"),
        action,
        serialNumber = $('#serial').val(),
        param;

    switch (id) {
        case "submit-all":
            action = submitUrl;
            ignoreValidationElements.length = 0;
            if ($('#collapsTwo').is(':visible')) {
                $('#collapsTwo input').each(function (index, element) {
                    var innerId = $(element).attr("id");
                    ignoreValidationElements.push(innerId);
                });
            } else {
                ignoreValidationElements.push("serial");
            }
            break;
        case "add-item":
            action = addItemUrl;
            ignoreValidationElements.length = 0;
            ignoreValidationElements.push("cID");
            ignoreValidationElements.push("cAdd");
            ignoreValidationElements.push("cNum");
            ignoreValidationElements.push("cEmail"); 
            break;
        case "save-all":
            action = saveUrl;
            ignoreValidationElements.length = 0;
            ignoreValidationElements.push("cID");
            ignoreValidationElements.push("cAdd"); 
            ignoreValidationElements.push("cNumer");
            ignoreValidationElements.push("cEmail");
            if ($('#collapsTwo').is(':visible')) {
                $('#collapsTwo input').each(function (index, element) {
                    var innerId = $(element).attr("id");
                    ignoreValidationElements.push(innerId);
                });
            } else {
                ignoreValidationElements.push("serial");
            }
            break;
        case "cancel":
            action = cancelUrl;
            ignoreValidationElements.length = 0;
            ignoreValidationElements.push("cID");
            ignoreValidationElements.push("cAdd");
            ignoreValidationElements.push("cNumb");
            ignoreValidationElements.push("cEmail");
            if ($('#collapsTwo').is(':visible')) {
                $('#collapsTwo input').each(function (index, element) {
                    var innerId = $(element).attr("id");
                    ignoreValidationElements.push(innerId);
                });
            } else {
                ignoreValidationElements.push("serial");
            }
            break;
    }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to add items to an `array` `ignoreValidationElements` which I can then ignore the validation on form submit.

If `#submit-all` is clicked then I want to ignore the bottom half of the form only. If `save-all` or `cancel` is clicked I want to ignore the entire form validation. And if `add-item` is clicked then I want to ignore the top half of the form validation. As you can see I'm writing the same code over and over. My question is, how can I make write minimal code for this scenario?

Comment: While there is nothing wrong with your approach, I have to say I find approaches where each function performs a... well... function :) more elegant and readable. I am not sure how your store looks like, but I would rather have completely different handlers for different actions (and buttons) and maybe put the common code (if any) in aptly named functions called from these handlers. Of course, style and taste differ, it's just an opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function ignoreValidation(ignoreValidationElements) {
    ignoreValidationElements.length = 0;
    ignoreValidationElements.push("cID");
    ignoreValidationElements.push("cAdd");
    ignoreValidationElements.push("cNum");
    ignoreValidationElements.push("cEmail"); 
}

$('.store-action').click(function (e) {
    var ignoreValidationElements = [],
        id = $(this).attr("id"),
        name = $(this).attr("name"),
        action,
        serialNumber = $('#serial').val(),
        param;

    switch (id) {
        case "submit-all":
            action = submitUrl;
            ignoreValidationElements.length = 0; 
            if ($('#collapsTwo').is(':visible')) {
                $('#collapsTwo input').each(function (index, element) {
                    var innerId = $(element).attr("id");
                    ignoreValidationElements.push(innerId);
                });
            } else {
                ignoreValidationElements.push("serial");
            }
            break;
        case "add-item":
            action = addItemUrl;
            ignoreValidation(ignoreValidationElements);
            break;
        case "save-all":
        case "cancel":
            action = (id == "save-all") ? saveUrl : cancelUrl;
            ignoreValidation(ignoreValidationElements);
            if ($('#collapsTwo').is(':visible')) {
                $('#collapsTwo input').each(function (index, element) {
                    var innerId = $(element).attr("id");
                    ignoreValidationElements.push(innerId);
                });
            } else {
                ignoreValidationElements.push("serial");
            }
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and let you know how I get on